# CakePHP Pagination Order by doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, paginator

I'm making an application with AngularJS & CakePHP.

I have one web service in Cake that might return data ordered but it doesn't do that, it returns data as came from DB.

This is part of my code:

```
     $this->Paginator->settings = array('limit' => 20, 'page' => $this->request->data['page']+1, 'recursive' => -1);
     $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Country', $conditions, $order);
```

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the signature of Paginator's paginate component  (See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination):

```
public function paginate(Model $model, $conditions, $fields, $order, $limit,
    $page = 1, $recursive = null, $extra = array())
```

The second argument you should be passing is fields, not order.

However, you can also just define the order in your settings array, like you do with a find condition.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I fix my code but it doesn't work: 
                        $this->Paginator->settings = array('limit' => 20, 'page' => $this->request->data['page']+1, 'recursive' => -1);
                       $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Country', $conditions, array(), $order);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 20,
        'conditions'=>$conditions,
        'order' => $order
        );
$data = $this->paginate('Country');
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it doesn't work, I'm getting the same output... :-(

Comment: I'm receiving by POST the sort condition and I'm doing this before paginate:
                    if(isset($this->request->data['SORTCountry_name']))
                    {
                        if($this->request->data['SORTCountry_name'])
                        {
                            array_push($order, "Country.name DESC");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            array_push($order, "Country.name ASC");
                        }
                    }
I send back $order via JSON and has "Country.name DESC" as value

Comment: I fix it allowing that user can sort by one field at time, then it works but if I want that user can sort by more than one field it doesn't work. But it doesn't matter it's ok anyway. Thanks for your help